# Hacer Hover en una imagen y que esta se para de inmediato con Slick Slider

Tags: html, jquery, wordpress

estoy implementando slick en mi web, para ello lo he ajustado para que el slider gire de manera continua si hacer la típica parada de imagen en el centro. El problema es que para ello he tenido que autoplaySpeed a 1 y el speed a 5000, al activarle la opcion pauseOnHover: true, al hacer hover, el slider sigue hasta el centro y luego se para.
Lo que necesito es que este se para instantáneamente cuando hago hover.

Aqui os dejo el codigo, esta hecho para wordpress:

```
<?php
$gallery = get_field('gallery');
?>
<section class="start0">

    <?php if ($gallery) : ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="autoplay">

                <?php foreach ($gallery as $item) : ?>
                    <?php if (!$item['optionen']): ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $item['bild']['sizes']['large']; ?>"
                             alt="<?php echo $item['alt']; ?>" data-lity>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $item['video']; ?>" data-lity>
                            <img src="<?php echo $item['bild']['sizes']['large']; ?>"
                                 alt="<?php echo $item['alt']; ?>"></a>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</section>
```

Y aqui la configuracion del script

```
 $('.autoplay').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 1,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 5000,
    focusOnSelect: false,
    pauseOnHover: true,
    arrows: false,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    variableWidth: true,
    centerMode: true,
    responsive: [
        {
            breakpoint: 768,
            settings: {
                cssEase: 'none',
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 480,
            settings: {
                cssEase: 'none',
            }
        }
    ]

});
```

Alguien me podria ayuda por favor?
Un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con estos valores para el slick:

```
          speed: 750,
          autoplay: true,
          infinite: true,
          autoplaySpeed: 0,
          slidesToScroll: 0.1,
```

Como en este
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q1qznouw/1120/)